# How to fix the init.d script of Nexus 3.0 (Milestone 7 Release)

Tags: nexus, nexus3

The shell script used to start Nexus 3.0 now calls a install4j launcher:

```
case "$1" in
    start)
        echo "Starting nexus"

$INSTALL4J_JAVA_PREFIX nohup "$app_java_home/bin/java" -server -Dinstall4j.jvmDir="$app_java_home" -Dexe4j.moduleName="$prg_dir/$progname" "-Dinstall4j.launcherId=245" "-Dinstall4j.swt=false" "$vmov_1" "$vmov_2" "$vmov_3" "$vmov_4" "$vmov_5" $INSTALL4J_ADD_VM_PARAMS -classpath "$local_classpath" com.install4j.runtime.launcher.UnixLauncher start 9d17dc87 "" "" org.apache.karaf.main.Main  > /dev/null 2>&1 &
```

The $INSTALL4J_JAVA_PREFIX evaluates to a single command su to change the user. Unfortunately it seems that nobody has tested this to be working under debian. Here is the result with set -x:

```
root@nexus:~# /etc/init.d/nexus start
Starting nexus
+ exit 0
+ su - nexus -c nohup /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin/java -server -Dinstall4j.jvmDir=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre -Dexe4j.moduleName=/usr/local/nexus/bin/nexus -Dinstall4j.launcherId=245 -Dinstall4j.swt=false -Di4jv=0 -Di4jv=0 -Di4jv=0 -Di4jv=0 -Di4jv=0 -Xms256M -Xmx768M -XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions -XX:+UnsyncloadClass -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dkaraf.home=. -Dkaraf.base=. -Dkaraf.etc=etc -Djava.util.logging.config.file=etc/java.util.logging.properties -Dkaraf.data=/var/nexus -Dkaraf.instances=/var/nexus/instances -Djava.io.tmpdir=/var/nexus/tmp -Dkaraf.startLocalConsole=false -Di4j.vpt=true -classpathroot@nexus:~#  /usr/local/nexus/.install4j/i4jruntime.jar:/usr/local/nexus/lib/boot/org.apache.karaf.main-4.0.3.jar:/usr/local/nexus/lib/boot/org.osgi.core-6.0.0.jar:/usr/local/nexus/lib/boot/org.apache.karaf.diagnostic.boot-4.0.3.jar:/usr/local/nexus/lib/boot/org.apache.karaf.jaas.boot-4.0.3.jar:/usr/local/nexus/lib/boot/nexus-branding.jar com.install4j.runtime.launcher.UnixLauncher start 9d17dc87   org.apache.karaf.main.Main
su: invalid option -- 'D'
```

Doublequoting and escaping the used doublequotes in the complete command doesn't help as the java vm starts but fails with an exception in install4j code:

```
WARN: file:/root/etc/config.properties is not found, so not loaded
Error occurred shutting down framework: java.lang.NumberFormatException: null
java.lang.NumberFormatException: null
        at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:542)
        at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
        at org.apache.karaf.main.ConfigProperties.<init>(ConfigProperties.java:222)
        at org.apache.karaf.main.Main.updateInstancePidAfterShutdown(Main.java:221)
        at org.apache.karaf.main.Main.main(Main.java:188)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at com.exe4j.runtime.LauncherEngine.launch(LauncherEngine.java:62)
        at com.install4j.runtime.launcher.UnixLauncher.main(UnixLauncher.java:60)
```

Did someone already fix the line in the script so nexus can be run by other users than root?

BTW - Who asked for this terrible install4j bloatware to be included?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See here for information on how to fix this:

https://issues.sonatype.org/browse/NEXUS-9437?focusedCommentId=344454&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-344454

Comment: One of the wackier fixes I've seen, as it's just forgets about all the parameters that the script sets together and shortcuts the command switch, but it works.

Comment: +1 even when it does not solve the problem in CentOS 6.5 and Nexus 3.1.0-04. Bizarre solution described there. I had to stay starting the service as root.